# Apache Beam Gradle build

Tags: gradle, google-cloud-platform, apache-beam

I was able to build Apache beam new version using pom but while using gradle I am facing issues with it like repository issues and I am also not known about after build our jar goes to which place because in maven .m2 directory was the target area can anyone help me in building Apache beam 2.6.0-SNAPSHOT USING GRADLE

Comment: Please provide information on errors you get or what procedure you're following in order to reproduce the issue. Also, check if this may be related to [this issue report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-4614), which is already fixed.